# What to do with these nodes to create radial gradient effect... Also how to add 3rd color to mix node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I am attempting to create a certain screen-like effect with my nodes here...

Here's the material I have along with the node set up, I annotated th e part I think I am having trouble with...:
[image]

[image]
I want there to be a soft radial gradient surrounding the face though, similar to a weathered screen.
Here is an example of what I have been unable to replicate below:

[image: Rachel's Bot]

Also, I have an extra face texture I would like to add as another expression. However the mix node only lets me add 2 textures. Is there a way to add another color?

[image: face nodes]

I will include both blend files below for reference...
[Boxbot.10 Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_GJQIZC9sloZ5R_y8EVADPCUceHJ-n4n/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In the texture you can a gradient texture and choose [radial].  If you would like to create your own radial texture you can illuminate a sphere.  You can quickly add the gradient texture and choose [radial] and update your image.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger
  I guess I dont quite mean "Radial" ... what I am trying to accomplish is have a soft linear gradient bleeding in from the top, bottom, left and right of the screen. I don't believe changing the texture to [radial] would solve the problem in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think atomicbezierslinger wanted to write "spherical":

So you can try this node setup here (i made it with default cube):

[image]

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I want it to do because the spherical gradient does not extend to the other faces/planes of the cube... if there were a way to make it an oval that extended beyond the 1 face & bled equally from the edges of the screen, It would be perfect. That aside, this solution is very close.